# MVP design with GWT ClickHandler

Tags: gwt, mvp

What would be the MVP approach for using GWT's ClickHandler?

I have a button in my view, which I would like to add a click handler to.

View
button.addClickHandler(?)

What gets passed in?  The presenter? newed up click handler?

Example case 1. View code:

```
this.myButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
        {
            myPresenter.buttonClicked();
        }
    });
```

In this case, adding a click handler to the button can't be tested...

Example case 2. Presenter code:

```
this.view.addClickHandlerToButton(this);

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        buttonClicked();
    }
```

In this case, GWT code (ClickEvent) is introduced in the presenter, which should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

i solved this this way:

register view to clickevent,
and handle it in view:

onClick(){
presenter.onButtonClicked();
}

probably the button has some semantic like "deleteEntry" so the presenters method would be "onDeleteEntryClicked" or "deleteEntry"

mvp says let view decide what kind of ui element to use and presenter executes the command.
so the logic behind "deleteEntry" would not change while you could substitute the button by other ui element -also without hasClickHandler.

Comment: This approach works, except the linking of the presenter can't be tested.  Is this OK?

Answer (score -1):

The button implements an interface called HasClickHandlers, which has a method for registering click events.

In your View interface you can return this interface to your presenter which can call addClickHandler on it.

View interface:

```
public MyView extends IsWidget{
    public HasClickHandlers getButton();

}
```

your view implementation:

```
public HasClickHandler getButton(){
    return button;
}
```

In your presenter:

```
view.getButton().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
....
});
```

Comment: If you new up a ClickHandler in the presenter, doesn't that expose view code in the presenter, as ClickHandler and ClickEvent are gwt classes?

Comment: yes they are, but they can be used in unit tests. basically there are two approaches. the one I described - the view does not have any logic. the other means passing in the presenter and registering events inside the view and forwarding them

Comment: the problem is, with this the ui could not easily exchange the button by other ui element without clickhandler. - see my answer

Comment: you can easily interchange with all elements that implement this interface or use a delegate. If you ui no more offers a clickable element its a significant change anyway... I have used both approaches and they both have advantages / disadvantages

Comment: it is no question of significance but what part does what job. i think it is not the job of interface to define that some action must be triggered by a click (what if a click and a key event and... should trigger the same action). it is enough to say there is some action.